# Younger readers: characters enter another dimension by walking backwards in a magic graveyard

Tags: story-identification, magic

This book was a series involving 4 kids traveling through different dimensions. There were possibly 2 boys and 2 girls. They would circle backwards in a graveyard to cross over.

One of the boys was called Adam.
In one of the stories, they are all blessed, which turns out to be a curse when the girl asking for beauty pales and starts to fade.

Comment: When you say they would circle backwards, was the word "widdershins" perhaps used?

Comment: Also, this may not be much to go on for someone who has not read the story. Can you recall anything else, even so trivial a detail as when you read it?

Comment: I don't know whether you have an email tied to this account for notifications, but [someone identified this series as *Spooksville* by Christopher Pike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255612/fantasy-book-about-walking-backwards-in-a-graveyard-to-an-alternate-fantasy-worl) in another question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fantasy book about walking backwards in a graveyard to an alternate fantasy world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255612/fantasy-book-about-walking-backwards-in-a-graveyard-to-an-alternate-fantasy-worl)

Answer (score 3):

From the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/255613/35) "Spooksville":

> Maybe the [Spooksville](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49699-spooksville) series by Christopher Pike? Main character is
> Adam, and the Secret Path seems to be walking backwards through a
> graveyard. (Found with a search that brought up [this result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GCNICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=walk%20backwards%20graveyard%20cross%20over%20adam&source=bl&ots=d3os2WSRRz&sig=ACfU3U2Sq0gYkFccBN3FwwB0MEfaJ0fk3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja5LWhq_nzAhUw8LsIHYImC1EQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=walk%20backwards%20graveyard%20cross%20over%20adam&f=false) in google
> books)

In the book "The Dark Corner" from the "Spooksville" series, there is mention of a "Secret Path".  The first book in the same series is called "The Secret Path".  Which is likely a reference to the route. From "The Dark Corner":

> "It's not that easy," Adam Explained. "First you have to trace a route
> all over Spooksville.  Then you have to walk from the front gate of
> the cemtary backward into the tombstone."

Comment: At least write a proper answer...