# Fantasy book about walking backwards in a graveyard to an alternate fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

I used to read a series of children's 9-12 or young adult aged books, the last time I read this book was at least 15 years ago when I was about 12 years old.

It was about a group of 4 children (2 boys and 2 girls), one of whom was named Adam (perhaps there was a Sally also?). All I remember, was that these children used to **walk backwards in a graveyard**, and they would find themselves in a fantasy world with demons and fairies; it was a very different world each time. One book, they found themselves in a castle and they find 4 gems and they are given different hyper qualities. One of the boys becomes very strong, and one of the girls (this I remember more vividly) becomes fair/beautiful until she becomes so white that she literally begins to fade away like a ghost. I believe that the graveyard exists in every reality/world that they travel to. It seems to be that they need to pass through there to get home every time.

One of the books had a yellow front cover, with a vortex multicoloured spiral in the centre.

I used to borrow this book from my local library in the children's section which was not too big, I have a small inkling that the author of this book had a last name from E-S from picturing the layout of the library (but I may be wrong).

I don't remember this book being particularly famous, I don't think I have seen it since.

Comment: [Looks like someone else was looking for this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138146/58193); no answer there yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe the [Spooksville](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49699-spooksville) series by Christopher Pike? Main character is Adam, and the Secret Path seems to be walking backwards through a graveyard. (Found with a search that brought up [this result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GCNICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=walk%20backwards%20graveyard%20cross%20over%20adam&source=bl&ots=d3os2WSRRz&sig=ACfU3U2Sq0gYkFccBN3FwwB0MEfaJ0fk3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja5LWhq_nzAhUw8LsIHYImC1EQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=walk%20backwards%20graveyard%20cross%20over%20adam&f=false) in google books)

Comment: This looks undoubtedly correct. You may want to flesh this out a bit more (there's a character called Sally, for example) and you may also want to post it on the question I linked in the comments that seems to be looking for the same story.

Comment: AMAZING!  THIS IS IT!  THANKS!